# Remove old files with date in the name

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

I have files with name as

```
filename_201702200800.tar.bz2
filename_201702201800.tar.bz2
```

and so on

I am looking to remove files which are 5 days and older.
The date in the files is of the format %Y%m%d%H%M.

Comment: Were those files always created on the day corresponding to their names ?

Comment: yep they are created at that date and time

Comment: @RajHassani: Did you try anything to solve this?

Comment: @Inian find /path/to/files -type f -ctime +5 -exec rm  {} + worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the creation time corresponds to the names, just use `find`:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -ctime +5 -exec rm  {} +
```

From `man` page:

> `-exec command {} +`
>
> This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by
>   **appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of
>   invocations of the command will be much less than the number of
>   matched files**.  **The command line is built in much the same way that
>   xargs builds its command lines**.  Only one instance  of  ‘{}’  is 
>   allowed within the command.  The command is executed in the starting
>   directory.

Comment: also, `-ctime` would be preferable rather than `-mtime` in this case, as the archives could have been modified by the user between the time of their creation and +5 days

Comment: the question asks about **Name Of The File** that has date not a regular file

Comment: Thanks!! @klashxx

Comment: @klashxx what's the difference between rm {} + and rm {} /

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment.

Can you use the mtime of the files?

`find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +5 -delete`

Otherwise, you could calculate the dates to find with:

`date -d "5 days ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M`